# pandas get position of a given index in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df
     A  B
5    0  1
18   2  3
125  4  5
```

where `5, 18, 125` are the index

I'd like to get the line before (or after) a certain index. For instance, I have index `18` (eg. by doing `df[df.A==2].index`), and I want to get the line before, and I don't know that this line has `5` as an index.

2 sub-questions:

- How can I get the position of index `18`? Something like `df.loc[18].get_position()` which would return `1` so I could reach the line before with `df.iloc[df.loc[18].get_position()-1]`
- Is there another solution, a bit like options `-C`, `-A` or `-B` with grep ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For your first question:

```
base = df.index.get_indexer_for((df[df.A == 2].index))
```

or alternatively

```
base = df.index.get_loc(18)
```

To get the surrounding ones:

```
mask = pd.Index(base).union(pd.Index(base - 1)).union(pd.Index(base + 1))
```

I used Indexes and unions to remove duplicates. You may want to keep them, in which case you can use `np.concatenate`

Be careful with matches on the very first or last rows :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert more than 1 index, you can use `np.where`.

Example:

```
# df
     A  B
5    0  1
18   2  3
125  4  5
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0,2,4], "B": [1,3,5]}, index=[5,18,125])
np.where(df.index.isin([18,125]))
```

Output:

```
(array([1, 2]),)
```

Comment: This is a great trick to get iloc-valid indices after getting "naive" indices from a conditional such as: `df[df[col]==value].index.tolist()`