# How do i find the iloc of a row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an indexed pandas dataframe. By searching through its index, I find a row of interest. How do I find out the iloc of this row?

Example:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01 -0.077564  0.310565  1.112333  1.023472
2000-01-02 -0.377221 -0.303613 -1.593735  1.354357
2000-01-03  1.023574 -0.139773  0.736999  1.417595
2000-01-04 -0.191934  0.319612  0.606402  0.392500
2000-01-05 -0.281087 -0.273864  0.154266  0.374022
2000-01-06 -1.953963  1.429507  1.730493  0.109981
2000-01-07  0.894756 -0.315175 -0.028260 -1.232693
2000-01-08 -0.032872 -0.237807  0.705088  0.978011

window_stop_row = df[df.index < '2000-01-04'].iloc[-1]
window_stop_row
Timestamp('2000-01-08 00:00:00', offset='D')
#which is the iloc of window_stop_row?
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "searching through its index"?

Comment: What did you find? Number of position or label of index?

Comment: @filmor: smth like window_start_row = values[values.Timestamp < row.Timestamp - window_length][-1]. I need the iloc of window_start_row

Comment: @anton: I found the whole row. I need some values from its cells, but i also need its iloc.

Comment: ```df.index.get_loc(window_stop_row.name)```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837633/pandas-get-position-of-a-given-index-in-dataframe

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want the `.name` attribute and pass this to [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
In [131]:
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df

Out[131]:
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.095234 -1.000863  0.899732 -1.742152
2000-01-02 -0.517544 -1.274137  1.734024 -1.369487
2000-01-03  0.134112  1.964386 -0.120282  0.573676
2000-01-04 -0.737499 -0.581444  0.528500 -0.737697
2000-01-05 -1.777800  0.795093  0.120681  0.524045
2000-01-06 -0.048432 -0.751365 -0.760417 -0.181658
2000-01-07 -0.570800  0.248608 -1.428998 -0.662014
2000-01-08 -0.147326  0.717392  3.138620  1.208639

In [133]:    
window_stop_row = df[df.index < '2000-01-04'].iloc[-1]
window_stop_row.name

Out[133]:
Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00', offset='D')

In [134]:
df.index.get_loc(window_stop_row.name)

Out[134]:
2
```

`get_loc` returns the ordinal position of the label in your index which is what you want:

```
In [135]:    
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(window_stop_row.name)]

Out[135]:
A    0.134112
B    1.964386
C   -0.120282
D    0.573676
Name: 2000-01-03 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

if you just want to search the index then so long as it is sorted then you can use [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html#pandas.Series.searchsorted):

```
In [142]:
df.index.searchsorted('2000-01-04') - 1

Out[142]:
2
```

Comment: @lmsasu which bit? the `.name` attribute is not so obvious but the rest is reasonable to me

Comment: @lmsasu if you want to search the index, then so long as the index is sorted then this would give you what you want: `In [138]:
df.index.searchsorted('2000-01-04') - 1
Out[138]:
2`

Comment: I would have loved to use this, but I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214275/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-name

Comment: IMO, the method ought to be named `get_iloc`, as it's the integer location that it's returning. The name `get_loc` seems incorrect.

Comment: @sdbbs Use `.name` on a row, not on the dataframe.

Answer (score 9):

While [`pandas.Index.get_loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) will only work if you have a single key, the following paradigm will also work getting the `iloc` of multiple elements:

```
np.argwhere(condition).flatten()   # array of all iloc where condition is True
```

In your case, picking the latest element where `df.index < '2000-01-04'`:

```
np.argwhere(df.index < '2000-01-04').flatten()[-1]  # returns 2
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you could call index for your case:

```
In [53]: df[df.index < '2000-01-04'].index[-1]
Out[53]: Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00', offset='D')
```

**EDIT**

I think @EdChums answer is what you want. Alternatively you could filter your dataframe with values which you get, then use `all` to find the row with that values and then pass it to the `index`:

```
In [67]: df == window_stop_row
Out[67]:
                A      B      C      D
2000-01-01  False  False  False  False
2000-01-02  False  False  False  False
2000-01-03   True   True   True   True
2000-01-04  False  False  False  False
2000-01-05  False  False  False  False
2000-01-06  False  False  False  False
2000-01-07  False  False  False  False
2000-01-08  False  False  False  False

In [68]: (df == window_stop_row).all(axis=1)
Out[68]:
2000-01-01    False
2000-01-02    False
2000-01-03     True
2000-01-04    False
2000-01-05    False
2000-01-06    False
2000-01-07    False
2000-01-08    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool

In [69]: df.index[(df == window_stop_row).all(axis=1)]
Out[69]: DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I would like to get the answer "2", the iloc of this line. This is the question for me - how do i get this number?

Comment: After Anton's edit: it would be nice to make use of the index and search based on it. It is expected that index-based searching works faster.

Comment: Use @EdChums results for that.

Answer (score -1):

You could try looping through each row in the dataframe:

```
    for row_number,row in dataframe.iterrows():
        if row['column_header'] == YourValue:
            print row_number
```

This will give you the row with which to use the iloc function

Comment: This will be incredibly slow on large frames