# Selecting rows before and after rows of interest in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, selection

Let's say I have a time series dataframe with a categorical variable and a value:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'category': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 11), 'value': np.random.rand(11)}, index=pd.date_range('2015-04-20','2015-04-30'))

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
           category     value
2015-04-20        D  0.220804
2015-04-21        A  0.992445
2015-04-22        A  0.743648
2015-04-23        B  0.337535
2015-04-24        B  0.747340
2015-04-25        B  0.839823
2015-04-26        D  0.292628
2015-04-27        D  0.906340
2015-04-28        B  0.244044
2015-04-29        A  0.070764
2015-04-30        D  0.132221
```

If I'm interested in rows with category A, filtering to isolate them is trivial. But what if I'm interested in the n rows ***before*** category A's as well? If n=2, I'd like to see something like:

```
In [5]: df[some boolean indexing]
Out[5]:
           category     value
2015-04-20        D  0.220804
2015-04-21        A  0.992445
2015-04-22        A  0.743648
2015-04-27        D  0.906340
2015-04-28        B  0.244044
2015-04-29        A  0.070764
```

Similarly, what if I'm interested in the n rows ***around*** category A's? Again if n=2, I'd like to see this:

```
In [5]: df[some other boolean indexing]
Out[5]:
           category     value
2015-04-20        D  0.220804
2015-04-21        A  0.992445
2015-04-22        A  0.743648
2015-04-23        B  0.337535
2015-04-24        B  0.747340
2015-04-27        D  0.906340
2015-04-28        B  0.244044
2015-04-29        A  0.070764
2015-04-30        D  0.132221
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837633/pandas-get-position-of-a-given-index-in-dataframe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `n` rows around category A's:

```
In [223]: idx = df.index.get_indexer_for(df[df.category=='A'].index)

In [224]: n = 1

In [225]: df.iloc[np.unique(np.concatenate([np.arange(max(i-n,0), min(i+n+1, len(df)))
                                            for i in idx]))]
Out[225]:
           category     value
2015-04-20        D  0.220804
2015-04-21        A  0.992445
2015-04-22        A  0.743648
2015-04-23        B  0.337535
2015-04-28        B  0.244044
2015-04-29        A  0.070764
2015-04-30        D  0.132221

In [226]: n = 2

In [227]: df.iloc[np.unique(np.concatenate([np.arange(max(i-n,0), min(i+n+1, len(df)))
                                            for i in idx]))]
Out[227]:
           category     value
2015-04-20        D  0.220804
2015-04-21        A  0.992445
2015-04-22        A  0.743648
2015-04-23        B  0.337535
2015-04-24        B  0.747340
2015-04-27        D  0.906340
2015-04-28        B  0.244044
2015-04-29        A  0.070764
2015-04-30        D  0.132221
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how this could be solved when looking at a grouped dataframe?

Comment: I did something like this 
```def takeRange(df: pd.DataFrame, range: int):
    idx = df.index.get_indexer_for(df[df["Stop"] != "Running"].index)
    return df.iloc[
        np.unique(
            np.concatenate(
                [np.arange(max(i - range, 0), min(i + range + 1, len(df))) for i in idx]
            )
        )
    ]```

Answer (score 6):

To answer your first question:

```
df[pd.concat([df.category.shift(-i)=='A' for i in range(n)], axis=1).any(axis=1)]
```

You will hopefully be able to extend the same (perhaps a somewhat clumsy one) approach to cover more cases.